# Check if the command exists in bash

Tags: bash, command-line, command

I want to check if a given command exists in `bash` and I care only about the native commands of the bash and not the scripts written by the user. When I refer to `native commands` I mean all those commands that are generally available to a user.

There are two commands

```
command -v
type
```

that can be used to check if the command exists. But it also returns a true for user written scripts whereas I want to restrict myself just to the inbuilt commands.

**Note:** I am not just trying to distinguish between a `bash builtin` and other commands because

type -t touch

gives `file` as the type, but this is a command available to the user by default. But if the user writes a script and then tries to run it then I would like to filter that.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The set of `bash` built-ins is fixed, finite, and [documented](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands).  Why do you need runtime checks?  You could just test for `bash` version with something like `BASH_VERSION` or `BASH_VERSINFO`.

Comment: By “in bash”, do you mean builtins? For example, `kill` and `set` are builtins; `bash` and `ls` are not.

Comment: @jw013 I thought Sachin might be trying to distinguish between standard commands such as `ls` and custom scripts. In which case the answer is that there's no such distinction. Sachin, if that's what you were asking, there may be a way to do whatever you're trying to do, but you should tell us what you're trying to accomplish without focusing on a dommed approach.

Comment: @Gilles: you put it right I am trying to distinguish between any custom script written by a user and any other command that we run from bash. The command can be builtins or as you pointed out `ls` and `bash` are not `builtins` but I will lick to consider them as valid and any script as invalid

Comment: @Sachin You'll have to define more specifically what you consider invalid (or what you want to exclude).  Would a script placed in `/usr/bin` by root be considered a user script?  What about a binary installed into `/usr/local/bin`?  Would `command -p`/setting `PATH` to some default value suffice?

Comment: Yes any script written by the user would be valid but not any script written by the user. I did not understand what you mean by `command -p/setting PATH to some default value`

Comment: @Sachin: "any script written by the user would be valid but not any script written by the user" seems contradictory to me

Comment: (Really it's a duplicate of [How to test if a command is installed?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/273955/135943), but that's a duplicate of the question linked above, albeit a non-obvious dupe.)

Comment: [How to check if a program exists from a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592620/608639)

Answer (score 11):

Not sure about returning true for just a shell builtin, but `type -t` will return the type of 'command', including "builtin":

```
if [ "$(type -t help)" = "builtin" ]; then
    echo "Help is a builtin command."
fi
```

Run `help type` for more information.